# How to draw the line for each group using R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I think it could be the problem related to ggplot, I have a data.table with multi-key and more than 1000 rows, two of which could be set as key. I want to draw the line for each group of the data-set.

For example, the simple data is(ID and Act is key)

```
ID  ValueDate Act Volume
1 2015-01-01 EUR     21
1 2015-02-01 EUR     22
1 2015-01-01 MAD     12
1 2015-02-01 MAD     11
2 2015-01-01 EUR      5
2 2015-02-01 EUR      7
3 2015-01-01 EUR      4
3 2015-02-01 EUR      2
3 2015-03-01 EUR      6
```

Here is a code to generate test data:

```
dd <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3), 
             ValueDate = c("2015-01-01", "2015-02-01", "2015-01-    01","2015-02-01", "2015-01-01","2015-02-01","2015-01-01","2015-02-01","2015-03-01"),
             Act = c("EUR","EUR","MAD","MAD","EUR","EUR","EUR","EUR","EUR"),
             Volume=c(21,22,12,11,5,7,4,2,6))
```

In this case, we can see that there are a total of 4 subsets. The graph should like this:
[image]

I tried the code below,but it is not what i want :( :

```
ggplot(data=dd, aes(x=dd$ValueDate,
                    y=dd$Volume,
                    group=dd$ID,
                    shape=dd$Act)) +
  geom_line(size=1) +
  geom_point(size=3, fill="white")
```

[image]

Thanks a lot！！

Comment: You grouped your data based on which column of your data table? In your code, it's the ID column. Then it should be only 3 groups.

Comment: yup , it is true , i should and the other column for the group!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are saying is that for each unique combination of `ID` and `Act` you want a separate line. Try this:

```
   ggplot(data = dd,
       aes(x = ValueDate,
           y = Volume,
           group = paste(ID, Act), 
           colour = paste(ID, Act),
           shape = Act)) +
    geom_line(size = 1) +
    geom_point(size = 3,
               fill = "white")
```

Note that you don't need the `dd$` for each variable if you declare `data = dd`.